# Angular NgRx Store Management : cannot able to update store via dispatch function

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have basic knowledge in angular ngrx store with simple
functionality with **reducer**, **action** files. But Now I want to separate
selector.js with **createSelector()** Method.

My problem : When I used
**dispatch()** method and select **action** It will create state but its not
updating values.

Here is my code :

**news.actions.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { News } from '../../model/news';

@Injectable()
export class NewsActions {
  static LOAD_SECTION_NEWS = '[News] LOAD_SECTION_NEWS';
  static FILTER_SUBSECTION = '[News] FILTER_SUBSECTION';

  LoadSectionNews(list: News[]): Action {
    return {
      type: 'LOAD_SECTION_NEWS',
      payload: list,
    };
  }
  FilterSubsection(subsection: string): Action {
    return {
      type: 'FILTER_SUBSECTION',
      payload: subsection,
    };
  }
}
```

**news.reducer.ts**

```
import { NewsActions } from './../actions/news.actions';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { News } from '../../model/news';

// define actions

export const LOAD_SECTION_NEWS = '[News] LOAD_SECTION_NEWS';
export const FILTER_SUBSECTION = '[News] FILTER_SUBSECTION';

// define state interface

export interface NewsState {
  newsList: News[];
  filter: string;
}
 

const mockNewsList = [];
// initial state
export const initialState: NewsState = {
  newsList: mockNewsList,
  filter: '',
};

// implement actions
export function news(state = initialState, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_SECTION_NEWS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        newsList: this.getNewsList(action.payload),
        filter: action.payload,
      };
    }
    case FILTER_SUBSECTION: {
      return {
        ...state,
        newsList: this.getFilter(),
        filter: action.payload,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const getNewsList = (state: any) => {
  console.log('action.payload:::', state.payload);
  return NewsState(state, { newsList: state.payload });
  // return state;
};

export const getFilter = (state: any) => {
  // console.log(state);
  return state.filter;
};
```

**sections.reducer.ts**

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

// define actions
export const LOAD_SECTIONS = '[Section] LOAD_SECTIONS';

// initial state
export const initialState = [
  'home',
  'opinion',
  'world',
  'national',
  'politics',
  'business',
  'technology',
  'science',
  'health',
  'sports',
  'arts',
  'books',
  'movies',
  'theater',
  'fashion',
  'food',
  'travel',
  'magazine',
  'realestate',
  'automobiles',
];

// implement actions
export function sections(state = initialState, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_SECTIONS: {
      return [...state, action.payload];
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**selector.ts**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { getNewsList, getFilter } from './news.reducer';
export const getNews = createSelector(getNewsList, (state) => state.news);
```

**Create Action and update state**

```
loadSection(item: string) { this.store.dispatch(new
NewsActions().FilterSubsection(item)); this.store.select(getNews).subscribe((dt)
=> { console.log('here', dt); }); }
```

What My question is I cannot able to retrieve news list in store state after calling method : loadSection.

**Here is my Example :** https://rb.gy/0rrl2

When you click on sections --> its generates new state--> but not updating -> news LIST

Comment: @AndrewAllen Thank you. Updated my question. Any Help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

The action types are different

Actions:

```
  LoadSectionNews(list: News[]): Action {
    return {
      type: 'LOAD_SECTION_NEWS',
      payload: list,
    };
  }
  FilterSubsection(subsection: string): Action {
    return {
      type: 'FILTER_SUBSECTION',
      payload: subsection,
    };
  }
```

VS

Reducers:

```
export const LOAD_SECTION_NEWS = '[News] LOAD_SECTION_NEWS';
export const FILTER_SUBSECTION = '[News] FILTER_SUBSECTION';
```

The value of the action's type needs to be the same as the action type that's used in the reducer.

Actions should be defined as follows to update state:

```
  LoadSectionNews(list: News[]): Action {
    return {
      type: '[News] LOAD_SECTION_NEWS',
      payload: list,
    };
  }
  FilterSubsection(subsection: string): Action {
    return {
      type: '[News] FILTER_SUBSECTION',
      payload: subsection,
    };
  }
```

Side note: I would recommend to take a look at the docs. The code in the snippets is not very maintainable and error-prone (as you have seen). There are better ways to manage it, e.g. re-use action types, or ideally, by using the `createAction` method instead.